# GPO Policies are not being applied

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I'm an inexperienced AD/GPO admin trying to setup AD and use GPO to manage my kids laptop. I can get some user policies to apply but not computer policies. I've been spinning my wheels on this for over a day trying to figure out what I've done incorrectly preventing the full GPO to be applied to the laptop.

I have provided some links to the GPRESULTS from the client laptop from an elevated cmd prompt as well as the report from the server on the GPO.

The scope includes: Authenticated Users; The laptop computer, and the user group for my children

One of the items set in the computer is dis-allowing the MS Store to be run, since you cant disable it in Win 10 Pro.

Any help that can get this GPO working would be appreciated.

https://pastebin.com/ygH1fiXa - Laptop GPRESULT
https://pastebin.com/aeaqDCj3 - Server Results HTML - Copy & paste into a .htm file and view in a browser

Comment: Is the policy linked or enforced?

Comment: The policy was linked and enforced, my problem is that it was linked to the wrong object.

Comment: Ah, yup, that would do it. Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I found yesterday was that the Computer was something I had added and not one that was put into the AD by joining it to the domain. Once I looked in the default computer OU I found what was created and used that to apply the GPO against.